# lua function argument expected near <eof>

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api

I try to use lua in a C++ project. For lua executing I write this:

```cpp
#include <lua.hpp>
...
luaEngine = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(luaEngine);

register_results(luaEngine); // For register c++ object in the LUA script as metatable

lua_pushstring(luaEngine, resultsId.c_str());
lua_setglobal(luaEngine, "resultsId");

lua_pushboolean(luaEngine, needReloadModel);
lua_setglobal(luaEngine, "needReload");
...
e = luaL_loadbuffer(luaEngine, script.c_str(), script.size(), NULL);
if(e != 0)
    // error message
e = lua_pcall(luaEngine, 0, 1, 0);
if(e != 0)
    // error message
...
lua_close(luaEngine);
```

And the lua script:

```lua
local Res = ResUpdateLUA(resultsId)
if current_result == "Normal" or current_result=='-'  then
    status = 'E'
else
    status = 'O'
end
needReload = Res:setShowAnalyte('2320', status)
```

That didn't work and I've got error message:

> ```
> [string "?"]:7: function arguments expected near <eof>
> ```

But when I add

```lua
print(needReload)
```

at the end of the lua script it works nice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you print out the contents of `script.c_str()` and `script.size()` that's fed to `luaL_loadbuffer`? Show both versions, one with the `print(needReload)` and one without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that Lua reached the end of the source after seeing `Res:s` but before seeing `(`.

I suspect that `script.size()` is wrong. But I can't explain why adding that line works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. Yes, that was trouble with `script.size()` coz when it was replaced to `e = luaL_loadbuffer(luaEngine, script.c_str(), strlen(script.c_str()), NULL);` that started work fine. Sorry for my stupid question.

Comment: In that case, use the simpler `luaL_loadstring`, which does `strlen` for you.